# How to match multiple columns in different sheets in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]
I would like to match the values of Column B and D in Sheet 2 , compare Column D & Column E and return the value of Column E in Sheet1-Column B. I used the formulas below and it is not working. The problem is most of Column A values in Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 are different. So I need to match both Column A. I will enter this formula in Sheet 1 Column B.

How can i change the formula? Help me

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$E:$E; AND(MATCH(Sheet1!$A2; Sheet2!$A:$A; 0);MATCH(Sheet2!$B2; Sheet2!$D:$D; 0)))

=INDEX(Sheet2!$E:$E; MATCH(Sheet2!$B2; Sheet2!$D:$D; 0))
```

Comment: Just to check the functionality you're looking for: If you put `=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet2!$A$2:$B$18;2;FALSE);Sheet2!$D$2:$E$7;2;FALSE)` in cell B2 of sheet1, would that give you the correct functionality? If yes, we can try to make your formulas match the same result ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `B2` of sheet1 you could put the following:

```
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),Sheet2!D:E,2,FALSE)
```

The inner lookup `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)` returns the code e.g. A
and then the outer lookup  `=VLOOKUP(innerlookupvalue,Sheet2!D:E,2,FALSE)`, uses this value to do a lookup against the range containing the content values.

You can drag this down for as many rows as you have values. You will need to decide how to handle values that are not found.

What may be a problem is when you say "The problem is most of Column A values in Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 are different", you will get #N/A returned as you can't lookup a non-match. As i said above, you would need to determine how to handle this.

Comment: Can you tell me Here A2 represents what ? 
Dont worry, i Will always have values and i hope i will handle it.

Comment: A2 is the range containing the value you want to lookup for example AA100 in the image for sheet1 you posted. This range would change as you drag the formula down column B e.g. cell B3 formula would reference A3 etc...

Comment: Thank you. But Whether it will also work for non Adjacent columns? For eg: I have values in Column A and C & D and F.

Comment: If you have different ranges please update your question and images in your question to accurately reflect this.

Comment: Okay. Thats not my problem. But maybe in future i can use it. So only i asked you. Thank you.